# how to distribute licensed packages with conda

Tags: release-management, conda

Conda is great for distributing binaries of open source software.  However, for some software in my industry, it is necessary for users to agree to licenses or submit their email on a webform before getting access.  I would like everyone to use conda, is there a way for developers to still use conda to distribute such a package?  A solution that is as simple as `conda install ...` should be possible.

The best solution I have come up with thus far is providing a download of the tar.bz2 bundle the user has agreed to the license, and then having the user run `conda install package.tar.bz2`.  Unfortunately this does not install publicly available dependencies (say from anaconda.org).  Another alternative is to have users download the package and place it in the conda_bld folder, but this is somewhat manual and requires user knowledge of their install.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably to make two packages, one with the actual package, and one that installs all the dependencies. The reason for that is, according to the official docs, `conda install ./pkg-0.0.0-py27_0.tar.bz2` implies `--force`, which doesn't install any dependencies. So instead, your users could do

```
conda install -c your-channel pkg-deps
conda install ./pkg-0.0.0-py27_00.tar.bz2
```

In the package `pkg-deps`, you should list all of the dependencies of the actual package, but that package does not need to install anything. Technically, this would be a [Metapackage](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/building/meta-pkg.html).

The actual package file can be located in any directory when the user downloads it, so far as I know, and supplied on the command line. There shouldn't be a need for the user to put the package in a specific directory.